# In Cyclical Cosmology (Big Bounce) is it possible the new universe will be different or the same?

Tags: particle-physics, cosmology, condensed-matter, universe, earth

Could it be a universe with similar laws to ours but a different configuration of matter, so there may be another earth like planet in this new universe?

Comment: This possibility is discussed in the Wikipedia article "Poincare Recurrence Theorem", an 1896 conjecture, by the physicist Poincare, that was validated mathematically by the mathematician Catheodory in 1920.  It requires assumptions that the universe be spatially finite, and, in a more recent quantum mechanical version, that the "constants" of physics be absolutely constant:  Even if those assumptions hold, however, there is no guarantee of any "local universe" eventually being duplicated in every detail.

Comment: The time scale for Poincare recurrence is described, by the physicist Brian Greene, as the longest known to physics.